# Is there a write only Map?

Tags: java

Is there a map equivalent to the NullWriter?  http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/output/NullWriter.html

I wrote the below, but a standard implementation would be better:

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

    /**
    * a "write only " that discards all values. Useful as a place holder for 
    * optional usage of a real map
    *
    * @param <K>
    * @param <V>
    */
    public class NullMap<K, V> implements Map<K, V> {

    public NullMap() {
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsValue(Object value) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public V get(Object key) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public V remove(Object key) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void putAll(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m) {

    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
    }

    @Override
    public Set<K> keySet() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Null map");
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<V> values() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Null map");
    }

    @Override
    public Set<java.util.Map.Entry<K, V>> entrySet() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Null map");
    }
}
```

Adding: The use case is in some cases I wish to record some data for use later, and in some cases I don't. Rather pepper the code with ugly

```
if (map != null) {
    map.put("frick","frack");
}
```

I prefer just writing

```
map.put("frick","frack");
```

and have the data thrown away if map is assigned to a NullMap.

Comment: What would be the purpose of such `Map` if it will always be empty? Is this a kind of mock or something?

Comment: Yep, `Collections.emptyMap()` (Returns the empty map (immutable).)

Comment: What would you need an empty map for ?

Comment: @njzk2, `emptyMap()` throws `UnsupportedOperationException` on `put()` that is not what OP needs.

Comment: If you need this for mockup did you think to use one of available mockup frameworks?

Comment: You can't use regular map? Just instantiate it and use isEmpty()?

Comment: As an aside, the docs for that `NullWriter` are terribly confusing. Does it write nothing, or does it write to `/dev/null`? There is a huge difference, but i suspect it is the former, because otherwise it wouldn't work on platforms which don't have `/dev/null`.

Comment: Note that the above class `NullMap` does not satisfy the contract for `Map`, because `UnsupportedOperationException` may only be thrown by methods which modify the map. The methods `keySet()`, `values()` and `entrySet()` should just return an empty set.

Answer (score 4):

Not to my knowledge, but one may make ones life easier by extending from TreeMap or HashMap.

```
public class BulimiaMap<K, V> extends HashMap<K, V> {

    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Yes that's easier. Don't think I could use that particular class name where I work, however.

Comment: The name BulimiaMap would suggest that it throws something. :P